# use http src in qt scxml data attribute

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to use http sources for data in Qt's scxml implementation?
In other implementations this works, but not in my Qt Version 5.15.3

When using a simple state machine, with it's data src pointing to my running flask script I get the following error:

```
qrc:/main.qml:15:5: QML StateMachineLoader: :/http.scxml:5:59: error: src attribute resolves to non existing file (:/http://localhost:8080/) qrc:/main.qml: 15
```

Can't I define remote sources for data?

The statemachine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" version="1.0" binding="early" 
xmlns:qt="http://www.qt.io/2015/02/scxml-ext" datamodel="ecmascript" name="http_test" initial="test">
  <datamodel>
    <data id="http_data" src="http://localhost:8080/"/>
  </datamodel>
  <state id="test">
    <onentry>
        <send event="entried" delay="2s">
            <param name="eventbody" location="http_data"/>
        </send>
    </onentry>
  </state>
</scxml>
```

qml:

```
import QtScxml 5.15

id:theId
property StateMachine stateMachine: scxmlLoader.stateMachine

StateMachineLoader {
    id: scxmlLoader
    source: "http.scxml"
}

EventConnection {
    events: ["entried"]
    stateMachine: theId.stateMachine
    onOccurred: {
        var d=event.data
        console.debug(d.eventbody)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt SCXML works only with local files

[image: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscxml-scxml-compliance.html]